# Smooth Function with Specific Roots

Tags: polynomials

Let $a,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. We would like to define a function $f(x)$ with the following properties:

1. $f(a-c)=1$ and $f(a+c)=-1$
2. $f(a-c+k)=0$ for $k=1,\ldots, 2c-1$
3. $f(x)$ is smooth.

One simple approach is to define a polynomial with these properties,

$f(x)=-\displaystyle\frac{1}{(2c-1)!}\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{2c-1}(x-(a-c+k))$

Since $f(x)$ is a polynomial, it is smooth. Moreover, by construction, $(a-c+k)$ is a root for each $k=1,\ldots,2c-1$. Finally,

$f(a-c)=-\displaystyle\frac{1}{(2c-1)!}\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{2c-1}-k=1$

and similarly $f(a+c)=-1$. It seems likely that there are infinitely many "types" of functions with these properties. Are there some examples that are particularly easy to construct (especially of the non-polynomial variety)?

Comment: $\sin\pi x$ works.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Certainly $sin(\pi x)$ is smooth and has a zero at each integral value, but how is condition 1 satisfied?

Comment: Sorry, I misread.